# how to select data by array index and (/) the data one by one

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following database table:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqWWe.jpg

in the "nilai" column I want to add up all the values. I've tried using array_sum in php and it works.
the problem is how can I select the data one by one then divide by the sum of all the values and finally the results of the division are accommodated into the "normalisasi" column one by one.

example:
3/19 = 0.078947368421053

Here is the code that I used to add up all the values:

```
        <?php $query=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM nkriteria ");
            while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                    $jumlah[]=$data['nilai'];
            }
                    $jumlah_nilai=array_sum($jumlah); ?>
```

I added

```
$normalisasi = $jumlah[0]/$jumlah_nilai;
```

that works, the code takes the data from index 0 then divides it by the number of values,

but I want the division to be done automatically starting from index 0,1,2,3 and so on

and the results of the division must enter the "normalisasi" column one by one according to the index.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query - but note that you wouldn't normally store derived data

Answer (score 0):

Use **foreach** or **for** loop to select data one by one

```
foreach ($jumlah as $value) {
   $normalisasi = $value/$jumlah_nilai;
}

for ($i=0; $i<count($jumlah); $i++) {
    $normalisasi = $jumlah[$i]/$jumlah_nilai;
}
```

Comment: it's work, but when I display "$normalisasi" why only 1 value appears? not all values from the database appear.

Comment: Hey Ardian Sorry for late reply. I forgot to mention a thing. Put array_push($normalisasi, $jumlah[$i]/$jumlah_nilai) in the for loop.